# Perform the action on all the files in directory

Tags: java, file, file-io, file-handling

Right now i am choosing a file and it working good.

```
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System
                .getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop"));
        int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(fileChooser);
        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        }
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()));
```

it helps me to perform the read and write operation on the selected file.

But i want to add functionality such that i select the folder and it perform the read and write operations on all the files present in it or if i switch inside folder i can select a file on which i need to perform action

i tried

```
    chooser = new JFileChooser(); 
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    chooser.setDialogTitle(choosertitle);
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```

But it is not working.

Please help

Comment: Define *"But it is not working."*

Comment: it help me to choose that folder and if i print the same ... it will give me the name of folder. But i want to select all the files inside that folder.

Comment: So, something like [`File#listFiles`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) then?

Answer (score 1):

`JFileChooser` will return you the selected `File`, which will the folder that the user selected, you need to use something like [`File#listFiles`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) which will return an array of all the `File`s within the selected folder.

With this, you can then loop the array and process the indvidual files...

```
chooser = new JFileChooser(); 
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
chooser.setDialogTitle(choosertitle);
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(fileChooser);
if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

    File folder = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    for (File file : listOfFiles) {
        // Process the file...
    }
```

Comment: it will work for all the files in the given folder.
But here i need if user select a folder then it perform the operation on all the files inside it.
if user want to select a single file inside that folder he should be able to do that.

Comment: Then don't use `DIRECTORIES_ONLY`...use [`JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES).  You will need to check the resulting selected `File` to see if it [`isFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile()) or [`isDirectory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory()) and take appropriate action. See [How to Use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) for more details...